# У псевдоэлемента текст заменяется иконками

Tags: css

Если в псевдоэлемент добавить текст на кириллице, то текст отображается нормально на странице, а если текст на латинице, то каким-то странным образом вместо текста показываются иконки.

```
[lang="ru-RU"] .element::before {
    content:'поиск';
}
[lang="en-US"] .element::before {
    content:'search';
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

подскажите, как настроить, чтобы вместо иконок показывался текст: search ?

Comment: используете шрифтовые иконки?

Comment: @meine так наоборот хочет что бы текст выводился

Comment: @MaximLensky, вот я и спрашиваю)

Comment: @meine, вроде используются revicons, они как-то влияют?

Comment: Возможно там задан русский шрифт, у которого вырезана латиница, и латинские символы фолбэчатся в иконковый шрифт, который зачем-то задан по дефолту под русским. Короче начните с проверки шрифта.

Comment: да, шрифт иконок переопределял шрифт текста, разобрался